# Changing which view stretches when using auto layout and pinning

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am updating my app to handle the iPhone 5 layout. I have a view that has a variety of components.

I am using auto layout and almost have everything setup correctly. My challenge is that I have pinned two views so that they have a vertical spacing of 0. This makes sure that one of the views stretches so that the items stay touching. However, I want the view that is currently stretching to stay in place, and for the other view to stretch and meet at the edges. Does this make any sense? Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to fix the height of a view put a constraints with the height of the view and the other view will be fixed by bottome end the vertical spacing will be 0 betwwen those views.